# Changing A Different Class Display on Hover with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, traversal

Ok, here's what I'm trying to do. I have a DIV box with a child element set with DISPLAY: NONE;. I'm trying to use Jquery so that when the mouse enters the parent DIV box, the child element is made visible, and then hides when the mouse leaves the parent DV. There will be multiple divs on the page with these classes. For some reason it's not working. Any ideas? Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">  
     <span class="handle" style="display: none;">My Handle</span>
     <p>Child Text</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.parent').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).next('.handle').show();
    });
    $('.parent').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).next('.handle').hide();
    });
})
```

Comment: Have you considered the CSS only solution below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.parent').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('.handle').show();
    });
    $('.parent').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.handle').hide();
    });
})
```

Or even better, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.parent').hover(function(){
        $('.handle', this).show();
    },
    function(){
        $('.handle', this).hide();
     });
   );
})
```

Comment: I would recommend specifying the element type. It speeds up the query a bit.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: The OP might want to change element from `span` to some other element. Keep it generic where possible so as to avoid future issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your goal without jQuery:

```
 .parent .handle{  
    display:none;  
 }  
 .parent:hover .handle{
    display:inline;
 }

<div class="parent">  
   <span class="handle">My Handle</span>
   <p>Child Text</p>  
</div>
```

And you should probably use CSS only because it removes the need for Javascript.

Tested FF and Safari

Comment: This will not work. Once the element is hidden I was unable to detect it. *Tested in Firefox only*.

Comment: In the end, I'm using jQuery for more then just changing the display, but this is a good solution for the problem as I presented it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use `hover`. This means you only need to run the query once.

```
$('div.parent').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).children('span.handle').show();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).children('span.handle').hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, instead:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.parent').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).next('.handle').show();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).next('.handle').hide();
    });
})
```